# VB.net - RsData Query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've got the following situation that I need a bit of help with.

I'm pulling through some site locations to a string from a field in a DB using RsData.

strsite = rsData("Site")

Now the issue I've got is that some of items in the table have multiple rows with different sites.

How would I therefore check if multiple values exist and if so set strSite = "Various"

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to handle multiple lines in a single record or are you looking for how to determine if there are multiple records that are related to some search criteria?

Comment: Multiple records related to a search criteria. I use a stored procedure that will draw the 'site' value but sometimes will return multiple records with multiple sites which is where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If YourRecordSetObject.RecordCount > 1 Then

  strsite = "Various"

Else

  strsite = rsData("Site")

End If
```